# Hide elements from QGIS-Browser

Tags: qgis

I have a lot of services saved in my QGIS-Browser (a few WFS, WMS ...).
But there are also a few service-types I do not use.
For a clean QGIS-GUI I search for a way to hide some Elements in the QGIS-Browser.

I know how to hide Disks in the Browser, but I don't know how to hide Service-Types like SpatiaLite or Oracle.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Settings -> Interface Customization -> Browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write yourself a `Regular expression` and apply it as a filter.

1. Click the Filter Icon in the QGIS Browser
2. Click the Wrench icon and select Regular Expression
3. Create your Regular Expression like: `^(?!(?:Oracle|GeoPackage|SpatiaLite|N:\\|Project Home|)$).*$` to exclude specific entries

[image]

Comment: This works well! But i need to insert the Expression every time. Is there a possibility to save and reuse it automatically when i start QGIS?